# Creating Web Token issue

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to create and use a JWT for authorization in a .Net Core 2 web api app.  This line produces the error in bold below:

```
public string Value => new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(this.token);
```

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'IDX10603: The algorithm: 'HS256'
>   requires the SecurityKey.KeySize to be greater than '128' bits.
>   KeySize reported: '96'.'

---

Here is the complete code below.  Source is from:

https://github.com/TahirNaushad/Fiver.Security.Bearer/blob/master/Fiver.Security.Bearer.Helpers/JwtToken.cs

```cs
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost, Route("CreateToken")]       
    public IActionResult CreateToken([FromBody]RegisterMemberModel inputModel)
    {
        var token = new JwtTokenBuilder()
                            .AddSecurityKey(JwtSecurityKey.Create("fiversecret "))
                            .AddSubject("james bond")
                            .AddIssuer("Fiver.Security.Bearer")
                            .AddAudience("Fiver.Security.Bearer")
                            .AddClaim("MembershipId", "111")
                            .AddExpiry(1)
                            .Build();

        return Ok(token.Value);
    }


    public sealed class JwtToken
    {
        private JwtSecurityToken token;

        internal JwtToken(JwtSecurityToken token)
        {
            this.token = token;
        }

        public DateTime ValidTo => token.ValidTo;
        public string Value => new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(this.token);
    }


    public sealed class JwtTokenBuilder
    {
        private SecurityKey securityKey = null;
        private string subject = "";
        private string issuer = "";
        private string audience = "";
        private Dictionary<string, string> claims = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        private int expiryInMinutes = 5;

        public JwtTokenBuilder AddSecurityKey(SecurityKey securityKey)
        {
            this.securityKey = securityKey;
            return this;
        }

        public JwtTokenBuilder AddSubject(string subject)
        {
            this.subject = subject;
            return this;
        }

        public JwtTokenBuilder AddIssuer(string issuer)
        {
            this.issuer = issuer;
            return this;
        }

        public JwtTokenBuilder AddAudience(string audience)
        {
            this.audience = audience;
            return this;
        }

        public JwtTokenBuilder AddClaim(string type, string value)
        {
            this.claims.Add(type, value);
            return this;
        }

        public JwtTokenBuilder AddClaims(Dictionary<string, string> claims)
        {
            this.claims.Union(claims);
            return this;
        }

        public JwtTokenBuilder AddExpiry(int expiryInMinutes)
        {
            this.expiryInMinutes = expiryInMinutes;
            return this;
        }

        public JwtToken Build()
        {
            EnsureArguments();

            var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
          new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, this.subject),
          new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        }
            .Union(this.claims.Select(item => new Claim(item.Key, item.Value)));

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                              issuer: this.issuer,
                              audience: this.audience,
                              claims: claims,
                              expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(expiryInMinutes),
                              signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(
                                                        this.securityKey,
                                                        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));

            return new JwtToken(token);
        }    

        private void EnsureArguments()
        {
            if (this.securityKey == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Security Key");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.subject))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Subject");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.issuer))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Issuer");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.audience))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Audience");
        }

    }
```

Comment: I've a repo for example JWT authentication, check it's`Startup` and `AccountController`. https://github.com/lugrugzo/WebApiJwt/

Comment: Thank you very much Sirwan!!  Was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> Block size: the size of the data block the underlying hash algorithm
>   operates upon. For SHA-256, this is 512 bits, for SHA-384 and SHA-512,
>   this is 1024 bits.
>
> Output length: the size of the hash value produced by the underlying
>   hash algorithm. For SHA-256, this is 256 bits, for SHA-384 this is 384
>   bits, and for SHA-512, this is 512 bits.

Therefore we require a 128 bit secret key. If you want to store this as text then a 128 bit key can be represented by generating a random **32 character length** string.

Comment: Thank you.  Not sure what changes I need to make to the code though?  I am pretty new to JWT.  Are you saying I should: replace the "fiversecret " text below from his original code with a random 32 character text string?

.AddSecurityKey(JwtSecurityKey.Create("fiversecret "))

Answer (score 1):

I got caught up in the same spot (props to the author or this howto -> [ASP.NET Core 2.0 Bearer Authentication](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1205160/ASP-NET-Core-Bearer-Authentication). The key length is the issue, probably a typo on the authors part.

Instead of;

```
JwtSecurityKey.Create("fiversecret ")
```

use

```
JwtSecurityKey.Create("fiver-secret-key")
```